# PHP preg_match between tags with PHP logic inside

Tags: php, preg-match

I have a dynamic sitemap creation script that recursively looks through the filesystem and when needed, opens the start of a file, then looks for the text between  tags. It worked when the setup was like...

```
<title>Page Title | Company, Inc.</title>
```

But now I've added a wrinkle and set up a way to manage titles and meta info via an admin tool. Just in case something isn't entered, I want to fall back to the old default title info, but my preg_match isn't working for this...

```
<title><?=@$page_meta_array['page_title']!=''?$page_meta_array['page_title']:"Default Title Here";?> | Company, Inc.</title>
```

The php function that I pass the page to looks like this...

```
function get_title($filename) {
    $retval = "";
    $handle = fopen($filename, "r");
    $head = fread($handle, 4096);
    preg_match(";<title>(.+)</title>;", $head, $matches);
    if(sizeof($matches) == 2) {
        $retval = trim($matches[1]);
    }
    fclose($handle);

    return $retval;
}
```

Can someone point me to the correct preg_match? I'd like to have "Default Title Here" returned from the second example above.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this might do it:

```
preg_match(';<title><\?[^>]*"([^"]*)"[^>]*></title>;', $head, $matches);
```

note that short-tags are deprecated, and may not work in PHP6.

Comment: Thanks for the help and the tip on the short tag syntax. Guess I'll have to get used to <?php echo $x ?> every time I want to display a variable. That sucks. I get the <?xml> issues, but I'm sure there could have been better ways to implement... perhaps adding steps IF I'm even using XML in my code???

Answer (score 0):

you first need to parse the PHP code, then check for matches. Why don't you just use the contents of $page_meta_array['page_title']?

Comment: It will use the array value if it's been set. I build a light admin tool to allow someone to set up title/meta desc/meta keywords for each page. The data used to be static and wasn't set on may pages. When I put in the code to pull the new data from the DB, I did the <?=@$page_meta_array['page_title']!=''?$page_meta_array['page_title']:"Default Title Here";?> part to keep what was previously static in place until they got around to adding a new title in the DB...